# C++ template class change static member's value

Tags: c++, templates, linker

I have the following classes - 
class `Matrix<T>` that stands for a matrix of objects of type `T`, and it's super class `baseMAtrix` that holds a static boolean variable `parallel_` common to all types of `Matrix<T>`.

I want to access `parallel_` but it seems my code does not link -

```
class baseMatrix {
protected:
    static bool parallel_;
};

template<class T>
class Matrix : baseMatrix{

public:
    static void setParallel (bool parallel){
        if(parallel != baseMAtrix::parallel_){
            cout << "message" << endl;
        }
        baseMAtrix::parallel_ = parallel;
    }
};
```

I get the this message -

```
`CMakeFiles/ex3.dir/Tester.cpp.o:Tester.cpp:(.rdata$.refptr._ZN10baseMatrix9_parallelE[.refptr._ZN10baseMatrix9_parallelE]+0x0): undefined reference to `baseMatrix::_parallel'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status`
```

the `Tester.cpp` file is where I call `setParallel` -

`Matrix<int>::setParallel(true);`

is this the proper way to call `setParallel`?

is this the proper way to access `baseMatrix::_parallel`?

Comment: Technically you just need to define the variable. `bool baseMatrix::_parallel;` at global scope somewhere. By the way, you can probably avoid much extra work by avoiding global variables (which this is), and by using a single convention for capitalization of type names.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf what do you mean? why does MAtrix cannot acces a member of its super class?
I cant define a global variable because im not the onw to use the class

Comment: Also, instead of the convention with leading underscore, consider trailing underscore (e.g. as used in Boost). Leading underscore is a convention used for different things, namely for names defined by the implementation. Thus leading underscore is reserved in the global namespace.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf ok, I changed the name, but the problem wasnt solved

Comment: @proton The name wasn't cause of this problem, but you shouldn't use names with leading underscore. If implementation defined macro, for example `#define _parallel "Hello world"`, your code would become a mess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to stay just-header-friendly, you could change base class to template:

```
template<class T>
class baseMatrix 
{
protected:
    static bool _parallel;
};

template<class T>
bool baseMatrix<T>::_parallel;

template<class T>
class Matrix : baseMatrix<void>
...
```

This way there is no need for `baseMatrix::_parallel` in `cpp` file.

Comment: the point baseMAtrix is to make sure I can change the value of  `parallel_` to all instants of `Matrix<T>` regardless of `T`.

Comment: @proton: It's technically OK if you inherit from a single specialization such as `baseMatrix<void>`. I took the liberty of editing the answer to do that. There is a special exemption for template classes that makes this valid code even if the header is used in multiple translation units (no linker conflict on the definition of `_parallel`).

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf Thanks the for edit, that solves it well :)